# Difference between Sententia and Opinio?

Tags: meaning, word-comparison

Could you give some examples of sentences showing the difference between *Opinio* and *Sentencia*?

Aren't both good translations for "opinions?"

"Through" and "opinion" seems to be translated by both: opinio, and sententia.

How I understood what I found in dictionaries and books:

Only "opinio" means "idea" and "hypothesis" (true?)
I know that "sententia" can also mean a sentence, a maxim, a concept

but when they both mean "opinion" what is the difference between those 2 words, are they "perfect" synonyms?

Comment: "*Sententia* is the view of a subject, resting upon clear perception and acquired conviction, like γνώμη; *opinio*, an opinion resting upon mere feeling, like δόξα." (https://www.gutenberg.org/files/33197/33197-h/33197-h.htm#word_Sententia). no examples/evidence is given

Answer (score 2):

**sententia** is something you've given thought to and which relates to a given situation, a view; from this follow its uses as "thought expressed in words", "sense, sentence", "intention", "decision, judicial sentence", "moral maxim".

- *meā quidem sententiā* ('at least in my **view**')
- *ex sententiā; praeter animī sententiam* ('agreeably; against one's liking')
- *Quot hominēs, tot sententiae.* ('There are as many opinions as there are people', proverb)

  - There are still stronger expressions of certainty, like **jūdicium** and **arbitrium.**
  - Compare also **suō arbitrātū** ('according to one's wish').

**opīniō** is a universal expectation, an idea about something, like from prior experience; also a belief which can turn out to be true or false; a reputation.

- *ut opīniō mea est/fert* ('as I believe, I suppose that')
- *in eādem opīniōne esse* ('to believe so too')
- *praeter opīniōnem* ('against expectations')
- *opīniōne alicuijus mortis turbārī* ('to be distressed believing that someone died')
- *saepius opīniōne quam rē labōrāmus* ('often our problems are rather imaginary than real' Seneca, Letters to Lucilius 13.4)

Answer (score 1):

In the sense of “In my opinion...” both are perfectly fine and in practice synonymous. My impression is that *Meā (quidem) sententiā...* is used more frequently by Latin speakers today, possibly reflecting usage in standard sources, but I have seen *meā opinione* also (apparently *ex* or *dē meā opinione* is another option).